# Problem with launching ur_gazebo

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu, universal-robot, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am checking out [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ur_gazebo) on ur_gazebo. I have all the requirements installed. However, when I try `roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch`, it gives me some errors and says (Full output attached at the end)

```
[spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly
[joint_state_controller_spawner-7] process has finished cleanly
[arm_controller_spawner-8] process has finished cleanly
```

Still I can see `gazebo` working as expected (I think). I can run the `moveit config`, plan a path using rviz and execute and in gazebo it seems to be working fine. What am I missing here? I have no prior experience in this so an explanation on this is much appreciated.

`roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch` output:

```
... logging to /home/XXXX/.ros/log/fe8e0ec2-d9f5-11e9-a221-8c04ba099a14/roslaunch-tehan-l-l-13884.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://tehan-l-l:42425/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /arm_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
 * /arm_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/elbow_joint/trajectory: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
 * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_lift_joint/trajectory: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/shoulder_pan_joint/trajectory: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
 * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_1_joint/trajectory: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_2_joint/trajectory: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/goal: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/constraints/wrist_3_joint/trajectory: 0.1
 * /arm_controller/joints: ['shoulder_pan_jo...
 * /arm_controller/state_publish_rate: 25
 * /arm_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
 * /arm_controller/type: position_controll...
 * /joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 50.0
 * /robot_state_publisher/tf_prefix: 
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    arm_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
    fake_joint_calibration (rostopic/rostopic)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    joint_state_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_gazebo_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [13899]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to fe8e0ec2-d9f5-11e9-a221-8c04ba099a14
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [13912]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [13922]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [13940]
process[spawn_gazebo_model-4]: started with pid [13946]
process[robot_state_publisher-5]: started with pid [13947]
process[fake_joint_calibration-6]: started with pid [13948]
process[joint_state_controller_spawner-7]: started with pid [13949]
process[arm_controller_spawner-8]: started with pid [13952]
[ INFO] [1568798618.512260316]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1568798618.512910501]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1568798618.515966508]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1568798618.516420817]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
SpawnModel script started
[INFO] [1568798618.830303, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter
[INFO] [1568798618.832155, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1568798619.032186013, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1568798619.062803814, 0.052000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[INFO] [1568798619.138086, 0.121000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1568798619.275586, 0.157000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1568798619.341170165, 0.157000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ERROR] [1568798619.341286713, 0.157000000]: GazeboRosControlPlugin missing <legacyModeNS> while using DefaultRobotHWSim, defaults to true.
This setting assumes you have an old package with an old implementation of DefaultRobotHWSim, where the robotNamespace is disregarded and absolute paths are used instead.
If you do not want to fix this issue in an old package just set <legacyModeNS> to true.

[ INFO] [1568798619.341366169, 0.157000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /
[ INFO] [1568798619.342934098, 0.157000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ERROR] [1568798619.458619209, 0.157000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_pan_joint
[ERROR] [1568798619.460224030, 0.157000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_lift_joint
[ERROR] [1568798619.461534087, 0.157000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/elbow_joint
[ERROR] [1568798619.463498819, 0.157000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_1_joint
[ERROR] [1568798619.464802223, 0.157000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_2_joint
[ERROR] [1568798619.466222661, 0.157000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_3_joint
[ INFO] [1568798619.472698219, 0.157000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[ WARN] [1568798619.472966937, 0.158000000]: The default_robot_hw_sim plugin is using the Joint::SetPosition method without preserving the link velocity.
[ WARN] [1568798619.473005566, 0.158000000]: As a result, gravity will not be simulated correctly for your model.
[ WARN] [1568798619.473025461, 0.158000000]: Please set gazebo_pid parameters, switch to the VelocityJointInterface or EffortJointInterface, or upgrade to Gazebo 9.
[ WARN] [1568798619.473045111, 0.158000000]: For details, see https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues/612
[ INFO] [1568798619.495671740, 0.181000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1568798619.537266505, 0.223000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/XXXX/.ros/log/fe8e0ec2-d9f5-11e9-a221-8c04ba099a14/spawn_gazebo_model-4*.log
Loaded joint_state_controller
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
Loaded arm_controller
Started ['arm_controller'] successfully
[joint_state_controller_spawner-7] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/XXXX/.ros/log/fe8e0ec2-d9f5-11e9-a221-8c04ba099a14/joint_state_controller_spawner-7*.log
[arm_controller_spawner-8] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/XXXX/.ros/log/fe8e0ec2-d9f5-11e9-a221-8c04ba099a14/arm_controller_spawner-8*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333288/problem-with-launching-ur_gazebo/) by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2019-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> it gives me some errors and says

> ```
> [spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly
> ```

```
[joint_state_controller_spawner-7] process has finished cleanly
[arm_controller_spawner-8] process has finished cleanly
```

these are not errors, but merely informative messages telling you that those nodes have *cleanly* exited.

Everything seems to be working as it should.

> ```
> [spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly
> ```

this node is only responsible for spawning (adding) the robot in the Gazebo world. As soon as it's done, it's no longer needed.

> ```
> [joint_state_controller_spawner-7] process has finished cleanly
> ```

As the name implies (`_spawner`), this one also only is needed to load a controller. Once the controller is loaded, it's job is done.

> ```
> [arm_controller_spawner-8] process has finished cleanly
> ```

And the same for this one.

Nodes can shut down and *not* be in error. That's perfectly OK.

---

Edit:

> The thing is they exit without me killing them with `ctrl+c`

they are supposed to.

> You can see there are a few errors in the `roslaunch` output

If you are referring to the "no p gain specified for pid." then those are also not fatal and things will still work.

The Gazebo plugin has changed, but has remained bw-compatible. Refer to [ros-industrial/universal_robot#443](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/443) for some more context.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teshansj](https://answers.ros.org/users/37224/teshansj/) on 2019-09-18**:
Yes these are not errors. The thing is they exit without me killing them with `ctrl+c` You can see there are a few errors in the `roslaunch` output

Edit:

Thank you for the elaboration. I thought I was doing something the wrong way.